# What's the difference between "Factory Method" and "using New to create an instance"?

Tags: java, design-patterns

My factory method codes below:

```
public class DBFactory {
    protected DBFactory() {}
    protected static DataBase createDB() { return null; }
}

public class MySQLFactory extends DBFactory{
    private MySQLFactory() {}

    public static DataBase createDB() {
        return new MySQL();
    }
}

public class SQLServerFactory extends DBFactory{
    private SQLServerFactory() {}

    public static DataBase createDB() {
        return new SQLServer();
    }
}    

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataBase db = SQLServerFactory.createDB();
        db.connect();
    }
}
```

And I found it has no difference with the client codes below:

```
package factorymethod;

import db.DataBase;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataBase db = new MySQL();
        db.connect();
    }
}
```

The problem is, why I have to use Factory Method ? I think it becomes more verbose ...

Comment: Who says you have to use a factory method? You don't have to. And in this case, it doesn't make much sense indeed. It would make sense if you only had DBFactory, and if the factory method used some runtime information (like a config file, or system property) to return one of the Database implementations.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, you mean I could use "Simple Factory" right? Could you give me an example when I should use "Factory Method" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you made the classes [Abstract Factories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), and had the factory method non-static, it would make more sense because you could then provide the abstract factory at runtime to your client:

```
public interface DBFactory { // Note: interface, not abstract class
    public DataBase createDB();
}

public class MySQLFactory implements DBFactory {
    public DataBase createDB() {
        return new MySQL();
    }
}

public class SQLServerFactory extends DBFactory{
    public DataBase createDB() {
        return new SQLServer();
    }
}
```

then

```
DBFactory factory = // provide whichever based on runtime settings
DataBase dataBase  = factory.createDB(); // client uses whatever is returned
```

Comment: Hi there, but what's the difference between your code and just use new  in client?

Comment: @Alexis: The difference is something like this: 1) you have properties file which specifies which factory to use in application, for example: `dbFactory=SQLServerFactory` 2) Your application on start up reads the properties file and does something like this: `factory=Class.forName(dbFactory);`.  3) Your client code does this `Database db = factory.createDB()`.  Now your application is database independent, and you don't have to change your client code or factory creation code to add a new database.  Of course, you could do the same with a bunch of `if` statements.

Answer (score 3):

You use a factory method when you need a virtual constructor: different types at runtime.

A call to `new` can only create one type.

A factory can create a range of types, as long as they have a common interface or parent class, depending on passed-in parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Factory Method is a software design pattern that helps you implement instantiation of a family-like taxonomy of classes.

If you are only instantiating one class and don't anticipate your code to change in the future  to accommodate new classes, then you can safely avoid applying the pattern as it would indeed be unduely verbose / unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a factory method to implement a singleton design pattern.

For instance, let's say there is no need to have more than one MySQL() object at any time during the course of the application's lifetime. You can use a factory method to ensure that you never create more than one MySQL() object. Consider the following (psuedoesq) code:

```
public class MySQLFactory extends DBFactory{
    private MySQLFactory() {}
    private MySQL myObject;

    public static DataBase createDB() {
        if(myObject == null) {
             myObject = new MySQL();
        } 

        return myObject;
    }
}
```

With this code, you are pretty much guaranteed to never have more than one instance of that object created. This helps save resources when creating new objects, which can be expensive.

EDIT: I do believe I got out of scope of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Factory method pattern allows you to assign a specific concrete object without touching to the base class. This promotes the **Open/Closed principle** and **Dependency Inversion Principle**. This latter indicates: "never depends upon concretes classes, but make low-level elements (concretes objects) depend upon high-level elements (abstract ones)".

Indeed, imagine you have three kind of databases. Without a factory pattern (or abstract factory pattern), you would end up to this code:

```
protected DBFactory(String database) {
   if (database.equals("MySQL")) {
       this.database = new MySql();
   } else if (database.equals("PostgreSQL") {
       this.database = new PostgreSQL();
   }
   else{
       this.database = new Oracle();
   }
}
```

Factory template method allows you to specify this subtype through inheritance.
It is fixed when instantiated and cannot be change at runtime, on the contrary of the abstract factory pattern.

So without a factory, as soon as you want to add a new kind of database, you have to violate the Open/Closed principle and therefore **potentially break the existing working functionality** of the base class.

Anyway, in your specific case, there's no sense to use it.
Why ?  Because it is especially useful when factory is used by program (program's heart containing business logic) and not by the "main" method or any other process flow which just lump, feed and manipulate these logic components.

Answer (score 0):

@user984444 and @Mik378 get the point.
factory method can:
1.guarantee the instance to be singleton.
2.produce different concrete instances with different methods/parameters. And you don't have to check out the subclass/implementation.

better understanding of the factory method pattern is that,assuming you are in a factory,and you have no idea of the production process,but you can get the products you want. Let's have a look at the [class diagram](http://s1.linkvp.com/vpuml/tutorials/abstractfactorydesignpattern_screenshots/30_diagram_formed.png).
    MealFactory factory=new ChineseMealFactory();
    factory.prepareDessert() wll return ChineseDessert.
That's it.